# How do i export extension from Magento?

Tags: module, magento-1, export

I have some extensions installed and developed in my Magento store. I see their settings in /app/etc/modules files, but i would like to export one of them so i could implement it on other website. Is it possible to export module/extension from Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a module from on server to another all you need to do is copy over the files, see [Magento - Wiki - Magento folder structure](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento-folder-structure) for location of the files

There are "no real" module custom setting in `app/etc/modules/Example_Module.xml`, this mainly enable, disable and set the code pool for your module. See [Magento - Wiki - Customize Parts Of Magento Configuration](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customize_part_of_configuration)

Your module custom config (if any) are normally define in system.xml in your module etc folder, which is accessible  from `magento admin -> system -> config -> your module tab`. This data is store in `core_config_data` table in your database.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like the problem solved - i've successfully transfered module from one website to another. But, in my case i run into the problem:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /app/code/local/Modules/ModuleName/sql/Setup/upgrade-0.2.11-0.2.12.php on line 32

Seems like it's PHP fault, will investigate further. If you have any ideas on that, would be glad to hear!

Comment: Without seeing the content of upgrade-0.2.11-0.2.12.php then it hard to say why your getting that error

Comment: Sure, could we discuss it in private? Wouldn't like to share the internals, not sure how secure it is

Comment: just add line 30-35

Comment: `$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
try {
    $installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'pickup', [
        'group'        => 'General',
        'type'         => 'int',
        'label'        => 'Pickup',`

Comment: "[]" is php 5.4+ array format. Are you running php 5.4  on this server. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Right to the point! That was totally correct, thank you, R.S, your help is really appreciated!

Comment: So it is not possible to export the module via backend?